In Wagtail, how can you safely delete `PageLogEntry` instances?
I have a Django/Wagtail project that continuously updates Page instances with data retrieved via an external API. I somehow failed to implement a check to update and publish the internal instance only if the external data has changed. Therefore, Wagtail has created a lot of Revision instances. I fixed this erroneous behavior and purged old revisions using the Wagtail purge_revisions management command. That worked. But I still have a lot of PageLogEntry instances in my database.
I did not find a ready-to-use Wagtail management command and I'm not sure if PageLogEntry.objects.delete() is a good idea...
How can I delete/purge as many page log entry instances as possible without risking the functionality of my Wagtail project?
PS: The reason for my deletion request is that my database now consists mainly of PageLogEntry:
*** Page counts for all tables with their indices *****************************

WAGTAILCORE_PAGELOGENTRY.......................... 22942       86.6% 

